# The number of zeros in a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Does anyone know of a relationship between the number of zeros (complex and real) and the degree of a polynomial?  Specifically, if a polynomial has a double root, is it compensated with complex zeros?

Comment: The reason a double root is called a double root is because it counts as two roots; if you count them that way then an nth-degree polynomial has exactly $n$ roots over the complex numbers.  Otherwise all you can say is that an nth-degree polynomial has at most $n$ roots over the complex numbers.

Comment: "at most n *different* roots"

Comment: Look into the **Fundamental theorem of algebra**.

Comment: Yes, the property holds for complex roots too.

Comment: When a polynomial has real coefficients, you can always factor it as the product of first degree binomials for the real roots and second degree trinomials with real coefficients for the complex pairs. $$x^5-3x^4+4x^3-4x^2+3x-1=(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)(x^2+1),$$
$$x^4+8x^3+26x^2+40x+25=(x^2+4x+5)(x^2+4x+5).$$

Comment: @Timbuc: "at most $n$ different roots" would allow $n$ roots with multiplicity > 1, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Yes @Yves. That's what I wrote about the first comment.

Comment: @Timbuc: this is wrong, the total multiplicity would exceed $n$. The correct phrasing is "at most $n$ roots".

Comment: Didn't see the "multiplicity > 1", @YvesDaoust. The correct phrasing I wanted to convey is "at most n different roots", or "exactly n roots counting multiplicities".

Comment: @Timbuc: the message I want to convey is that "at most $n$ different roots" is misleading because of the qualifier "different". Because it seems to admit $n$ different multiple roots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of algebra states that **an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial has exactly $n$ roots**, provided you count them with their multiplicity.

This is equivalent to saying that **any polynomial has a root**.

Because if you divide a polynomial of the $n^{th}$ degree by the monomial $x-r$ (where $r$ is a root), you get an $(n-1)^{th}$ polynomial, which has a root, and you can continue until $n=1$ (this is called deflating the polynomial).

Said differently, any polynomial can be factored as the product of $n$ binomials.
$$x^3-3x^2+2x=(x-0)(x-1)(x-2),$$
$$x^5-3x^4+4x^3-4x^2+3x-1=(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)(x-i)(x+i),$$
$$x^4+8x^3+26x^2+40x+25=(x+2+i)(x+2+i)(x+2-i)(x+2-i).$$